# piping functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How can I have a JavaScript function let's say `piper()` which takes several functions as its arguments and it returns a new function that will pass its argument to the first function, then pass the result to the second, then
pass the result of the second to the third, and so on, finally returning the output of the last function.

Something like `piper(foo, fee, faa)(10, 20, 30)` would be equivalent to calling `faa(fee(foo(10,20,30)))`.

ps: 
It was a part of an interview, that I did few days ago.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: http://ramdajs.com/docs/#pipe

Comment: @MikeC I am used to see functions in js like this function ali( saberi,i)
{saberi(i)}, not in this way.with 2 paranthesis

Comment: @AliSaberi Remember: you can return functions from a function. [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40007211/calling-function-with-two-separate-argument-objects#).

Comment: Like a lot of interview questions, if you ever code like this you deserve to fail a code review. This is absolutely nuts. `f(...)(...)(...)` is not readable at all. As an academic exercise the hints are in your question: it "returns a new function".

Comment: underscore.js. has a `_.compose()` function that does this.

Comment: @tadman I'm not surprised you find `f (...) (...) (...)` as a ruby/php programmer, but your opinion on readability is purely subjective. Function composition, currying, and higher-order functions allow abstraction over arity which is a very powerful concept and one that permits some very expressive programs. You shouldn't dismiss it before developing an understanding of the domain you're commenting on.

Comment: @naomik Just because you *can* do something doesn't mean it's a good idea. It's like having a function with sixty arguments. You can do it, nothing's stopping you, but it's a nightmare to get all the arguments in the correct order. This sort of chaining is an anti-pattern unless you have a very narrow use case where it's actually simpler than the alternative. I do mostly Ruby, Node, Swift and Rust these days, PHP is just incidental and unavoidable.

Comment: @tadman so in Haskell, where every function has one parameter, is somehow bad because it may require some specific syntax in order to apply a sequence of functions? Javascript `f (a) (b) (c)` vs Haskell `f a b c` is no more a bad program just because you think the JS one is "unreadable" – it's the exact same program; just with a syntactic difference. So sure, you can write bad javascript and you can write bad Haskell, but just because *you* find a particular program unreadable does not make the program bad or a program that is expressed incorrectly.

Comment: @naomik I'm not even going to get started about Haskell. It's highly opinionated and able to get away with things that other languages prefer not to do. I've just given my opinion here, and like all opinions, it's a matter of perspective. Your case is an interesting demonstration of how this might be applied, but I think Haskell's use of this is a lot cleaner than JavaScript ever will be.

Comment: @tadman fwiw, I don't care much for Haskell, but it's not a bad language simply because it chose to be strict/opinionated about certain things; it solves problems in its own way and there's an active community to embrace the utility it offers. My point is that sequential function calls alone are not enough to indicate that a program is bad or "nuts". Yes, the syntax might look a little weird in JS, but that really doesn't matter. As someone that's unfamiliar with a particular *style* of programming, you cannot dismiss it on reading preference alone...

Comment: ... Anyway, I only raise issue with your comment because I think there's a better way to communicate your idea in a learning community like SO. You can say "`f (...) (...) (...)` is difficult to read for some and might benefit from a code refactor" – it's much more constructive and leaves completely unsupported opinions out of the mix.

Comment: @naomik It's just opinion here that it's hard to read, as unfamiliar syntax and conventions always is. Maybe this will become more mainstream, I've seen some *very* quirky conventions in Angular for example, but until it does it will require some explaining which is usually a bad thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For an arbritrary number of functions you could use this ES6 function:

```js
function piper(...fs) {
    return (...args) => fs.reduce((args,f) => [f.apply(this,args)],args)[0];
}
// Example call:
var result = piper(Math.min, Math.abs, Math.sqrt)(16, -9, 0)
// Output result:
console.log(result);
```

The same in ES5 syntax:

```js
function piper(/* functions */) {
    var fs = [].slice.apply(arguments);
    return function (/* arguments */) { 
        return fs.reduce(function (args,f) {
            return [f.apply(this,args)];
        }.bind(this), [].slice.apply(arguments))[0];
    }.bind(this);
}
// Example call:
var result = piper(Math.min, Math.abs, Math.sqrt)(16, -9, 0)
// Output result:
console.log(result);
```

Comment: `f(...args)` would be shorter, but I like that you made it preserve context.

Comment: So basically, It's ES6 problem and solution, right?

Comment: @Vic is right. This is not an ES6 *problem* (is there such a thing?), but a solution represented in ES6 syntax.

Comment: Added ES5 equivalent to my answer.

Comment: ES6 solution pins `this` to the global scope because of the arrow functions. Which is not good. ES5 example leaks `arguments`, which deoptimize the function. Otherwise, it's fine.

Comment: @gaperton, in the ES6 solution, `this` refers to the context of the `piper` function. https://jsfiddle.net/dy03q38x/

Comment: @trincot, sure, I know. Which will point to `window` in the browser.  Which is the global scope. Which makes is impossible to use this function for methods chaining. The bug.

Comment: @gaperton, did you check my fiddle (I added "use strict" here: https://jsfiddle.net/dy03q38x/1/)? I think it demonstrates quite well that `this` does not refer to `window` when you provide a context?

Comment: Nope. Does it demonstrate that capturing 'this' with arrow function and thus loosing the context is not a bug? :)

Comment: It was never my intention in the ES6 version to capture context with the arrow function, but to pass the context `piper` was called with to the functions that were passed as arguments to it. The fiddle demonstrates that this is indeed happening.

Comment: I don't understand your point. Your piper implementation is designed to be invoked with call or apply (and bind the supplied context inside)? Well, great then.

Comment: Indeed, that's it, or better put: it is designed so it *can* be used *also* with `call` or `apply` making use of the context argument when this is done. It is of course optional.

Comment: Interesting design choice. Considering the fact, that you can always bind context optionally with .bind. There is no any rational reason to do it intentionally inside of the functional combinators.

Comment: It is a shorter way than to have to bind each of the functions you pass to `piper` separately.  But even if that is not considered an advantage,it is not that much extra to mention `this` in the code the way I did it, so instead of asking *why*, I figured *why not*. ;-) Again, it is optional, much like the `contextArg` in the standard JavaScript `forEach`, and the likes.

Comment: "It is a shorter way than to have to bind each of the functions you pass to piper separately" -- if you do it right, you shouldn't do it separately. Just bind the result. piper( fun ) must return fun untouched, without any binding applied to it, and piper( f1, f2, f3 ) must do the same.

Comment: So, in the right implementation piper( f1, f2, f3 ).bind( context ) should do the job. Apparently, it's not true about yours.

Comment: What do you mean "should do the job"? Maybe you could provide a fiddle to illustrate what the issue is you want to highlight?

Answer (score 2):

Enjoy. Pure ES5 solution. Preserves `this`.

```
function piper(){
    var i = arguments.length,
        piped = arguments[ --i ];

    while( --i >= 0 ){
        piped = pipeTwo( arguments[ i ], piped );
    }

    return piped;
}

function pipeTwo( a, b ){
    return function(){
        return a.call( this, b.apply( this, arguments ) );
    }
}
```

Or, if you want the fancy solution.

```
function piperES6( ...args ){
    return args.reverse().reduce( pipeTwo );
}
```

Loops can be reversed depending on the desired direction.

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to [@trincot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40007933/1045510) (preserves context), but composes in the correct order and is marginally faster since it does not create intermediary arrays:

```js
const piper = (...steps) => function(...arguments) {
  let value = steps[0].apply(this, arguments);
  for (let i = 1; i < steps.length; ++i) {
    value = steps[i].call(this, value);
  }
  return value;
};



// Usage:

let p = piper(
  x => x + 1,
  x => x * 2,
  x => x - 1
);

console.log(p(2)); // 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative answer involving method chaining. I shall use ES6, though of course this can be transpiled to ES5. On benefit of this solution is that is has a very succinct TypeScript counterpart with perfect typeability.

```js
class Pipe {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    then(f) {
        return new Pipe(f(this.value));
    }
}
    
const pipe = value => new Pipe(value);
    
// Example

const double = x => 2 * x;
    
pipe(42).then(double).then(console.log); // 84

const result = pipe(42).then(double).then(double).value;
console.log(result); // 168
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution based on JS higher-order functions usage:

```
function pipe(...rest) {
  return x => rest.reduce((y, f) => f(y), x);
}
```

Usage:

```
pipe((a) => a + 1, (a) => a * 2)(3) // 8
pipe((a) => a + 1, (a) => a * 2)(2) // 2
```

Answer (score -3):

```
function f(f1, f2, f3){

    return (args => f3(f2(f1(args))));

}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for an arbitrary number of parameters. Throws exception when used with two of them. Interview failed ;)

Comment: i gave an example with 3 functions, but we can pass an array of functions.

Answer (score -3):

I think what you are trying to do is chaining.

```
var funct={
    total:0,
    add:function(a) {
        console.log(funct.total,funct.total+a);
        funct.total+=a;

        return funct;
    }
};


funct.add(5).add(6).add(9);
```

Comment: the method must be called like this: `piper(foo, fee, faa)(10, 20, 30)`