# Using reduce method for piping

Tags: javascript

There was an excellent post from trincot in Oct 2016 regarding construction of a piping function using the reduce method [(link to posting)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40007684/piping-functions-in-javascript), and I'm trying to understand the code in detail.

ES6 Version

```
function piper(...fs) {
    return (...args) => fs.reduce((args,f) => [f.apply(this,args)],args)[0];
}
```

Specifically:
1. Instead of `[f.apply(this.args)]`, `f(...args)` also works, but `f(args)` doesn't work. Why doesn't `f(args)` work?
2. Regarding the second parameter in the internal (anonymous) "reduce" function, why is `args` even necessary? . . ., i.e., why doesn't the following code work?

```
function piper(...fs) {
    return (...args) => fs.reduce((args,f) => [f.apply(this,args)])[0];
}
```

B. Alternatively, why can't we just use `[]` as a parameter instead of `args`?

```
function piper(...fs) {
    return (...args) => fs.reduce((args,f) => [f.apply(this,args)],[])[0];
}
```

ES5 Version

```
function piper(/* functions */) {
    var fs = [].slice.apply(arguments);    
    return function (/* arguments */) { 
        return fs.reduce(function (args,f) {
            return [f.apply(this,args)];
        }.bind(this), [].slice.apply(arguments))[0];
    }.bind(this);
}
```

Questions:
1. In the internal (anonymous) `reduce` function, why do we need the second parameter `[].slice.apply(arguments)`? i.e., why doesn't `[]` work in in its place?
2. Alternatively, why can't we just leave out that parameter entirely?

Many thanks in advance for helping me understand these issues at a deeper level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `args` passed as a second parameter to the `reduce` function are required to specify the *initial value* of the accumulator (that is, the `args` variable), so that on the first iteration,

```
fs.reduce((args,f) =>
```

results in `args` being the initial arguments (as expected). Otherwise, without passing an initial value to `.reduce`, the initial value of `args` will be *the first item in the `fns` array*, which definitely isn't what you want:

```js
function piper(...fs) {
    return (...args) => fs.reduce((args,f) => {
      console.log(args);
      return [f.apply(this,args)];
    })[0];
}

var result = piper(Math.min, Math.abs, Math.sqrt)(16, -9, 0)
// Output result:
console.log(result);
```

In addition, like this, the first function in the `fns` array will never be called at all.

Generally, you only leave out an initial value for `.reduce` when the type of the accumulator matches the type of the items in the array being iterated over *and* matches the desired type of the result, like with number manipulation:

```js
// sum:
const result = [1, 2, 3].reduce((a, b) => a + b);
console.log(result);
```

Of course, if there's ever a chance of the array being iterated over being empty, you should also provide an initial value.

In (almost?) all other situations, providing an initial value is necessary for the `.reduce` to work.

Comment: Even there it would probably be appropriate to provide an initial value of `0` so an empty array won't throw when calling `reduce()` on it.